# "Unable to find a javac compiler" error in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java project. It consists of the following hierarchy:

> Project:
>
> - Server (contains the server.java)
> - Client (contains the client.java)
> - Protocol (contains message types in .java files)

I am running this project with Eclipse. And I have gotten to a point that I need to test with a terminal. How can I use the build.xml file to format this so that it will work properly whenever I take it out of the Eclipse and run it in a server, but in the same basic project hierarchy shown above?

I receive the following error:

> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
>
> Buildfile: /home/taylor/Desktop/Java/TCP/build.xml
>
> build-subprojects:
>
> init:
>
> build-project:
>
> [echo] TCP: /home/taylor/Desktop/Java/TCP/build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> /home/taylor/Desktop/Java/TCP/build.xml:31: Unable to find a 
>   javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

Comment: I strongly advise you to use a more modern build tool, such as gradle. You can use ant, of course, but it'll be more work. Anyway, your question is too broad. Read the documentation and try something. Ask if you actually have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build.xml` is an Ant script file.  Just [install Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) in your OS.  Then, at the command-line, go to the directory that contains `build.xml` and type:

```
ant
```

It by default will look for and run the local file called `build.xml`.

For an example of how Ant build scripts are organized, see [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html).

Comment: Okay, I understand that. I am wanting to develop the project on one computer (my laptop), and then transfer the files to a separate computer (my lab machine) to test the functionality. I have ant installed (i checked the version and all). But I am getting errors when I try to run the **eclipse created** build.xml file to compile my code. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest posting the build.xml and/or at least the error messages.

Comment: I am trying to compile the project on a separate machine, just for further clarification. The machine is the same OS as my development pc and has ant installed as well. Here is the link to the [build.xml](https://gist.github.com/TrivialPants/3ae0b92d40117914c289) file on gist. I get the following error messages when I try to compile...

Comment: Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: /home/taylor/Desktop/Java/TCP/build.xml

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:
     [echo] TCP: /home/taylor/Desktop/Java/TCP/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/taylor/Desktop/Java/TCP/build.xml:31: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: I added the error message to the question to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Ant requires a JDK to run. A JDK has a `javac` compiler while a plain JRE doesn't. The path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre` points to a JRE, not a JDK. Try setting `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` instead.